# How can i make this options hide so i can use a scrollbar to reach them?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, html-lists

[here is what i mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk2Wr.png)

The question is: What can i do to prevent that and make the other options go like 'under' the div, so i can scroll to reach them?

this is the css code:

```
aside {
    background-color: #E63946;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2/5;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(5,1fr);
}
```

Also tried adding `overflow-y: scroll;` but didn't work. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl35Q.png) its how it look like.

Comment: More details include code

Comment: yes, my bad, i just add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `overflow-y: scroll` and setting a fixed height on the `div` container is correct but it's not the complete answer.

The reason why the 'options' in the grid are not overflowing is because the height of the grid's rows is set to `1fr` and the height of the elements (`div`s?) containing the 'option' text is not fixed. This means that the height of the 'option' elements will adjust to fit inside the grid. However, they will overflow if you add so many 'options' that the elements' height become the height of the text they contain. Try adding 50 'options' in the grid and you will see a scrollbar.

If you don't want to add 50 'options' and only want a few to overflow, set a fixed height on the grid rows (eg. `grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 100px)`) or on the 'option' elements themselves, keeping `overflow-y: scroll` and a fixed height on the `div` container, of course.

Comment: this is it, thanks a lot mate! It was cause the 'fr', if you set the height with pxls it just works!

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow-y: scroll;` on the options container and set it to a fixed height.
Here are [examples](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp)

Comment: thanks for helping @Jarne! I tried this but didn't work. I will edit the post and add a pic of how it looks.

Comment: Please provide us with HTML and CSS code for better assistance.
I can figure this out in a matter of seconds. @tobi